# ¿Por que me ocaciona problemas el operador or al comparar dos condiciones en un do while en java?

Tags: java, loops, operador, while

Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaDeMetodos {

    static Scanner teclado ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Escoje las opciones 'a' 'b' 'c':");
        boolean anulado=false;
        int precio = 5;


    do{
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String accion = teclado.nextLine();
        char opcion = accion.charAt(0);

        switch (opcion){
        case 'a':
            precio = 5;
            break;

        case 'b':
            precio = 0;
            break;

        case 'c':
            anulado=true;
            System.out.println("acabo el programa");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Escoje otra opcion");
            break;
        }



    }while(!anulado || precio != 0);


        if (anulado) {
            System.out.println("Acumulado es true");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Acumulado es false");
        }

    }
}
```

El problema es que si le doy a la opción 'b' del switch en consola no sale del ciclo (deberia salir por que es igual a 0) me regresa al ciclo y vuelvo a entrar al switch escojo de nuevo 'b' y no sale hasta que no escoja la opción 'c' es entonces cuando sale del ciclo while o por el contrario doy 'c' (que deberia salir por ser diferente del valor de anulado) y no sale hasta que repite el ciclo y escojo la opción 'b'. 

Ojala me pudieran ayudar a resolver mi duda de por que no a la primera rompe el ciclo do while y necesito forzosamente pasar por otra opcion del switch que rompa este loop.

Comment: El ciclo se repetira **mientras** sea *precio=5* o *anulado=false*; con *b* o *c* solo cambias uno de ellos por eso se repite; lo que debes hacer es en lugar de *OR* sea *AND*.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando escribes `b` solo indicas que `precio=0` lo cual `precio!=0` es `false` pero `anulado` sigue siendo falso por lo que `!anulado` es `true`.

Para que el operador OR de `false` y detenga el `while`, todas las expresiones tienen que retornar `false`.

Por lo que me llegan 2 opciones:

## 1

```
while(!anulado && precio != 0)
```

## 2

```
case 'b':
  precio = 0;
  anulado = true;          
break;
```

Comment: Aunque técnicamente lo que explicas (hay un "cortocircuito" en la evaluación de la expresión booleana) es correcto, realmente no es relevante para la respuesta; el resultado de un OR en que una de las expresiones es `true` es siempre `true`, se evalúen o no todas las expresiones. ¿Podrías corregirlo?

Comment: Disculpa, pero no entiendo lo que quieres decir con "el resultado de un OR en que una de las expresiones es true es siempre true, se evalúen o no todas las expresiones".

Comment: Que, realmente, se haga cortocircuito o no, el problema del OP no tiene que ver con qué expresión se evalúa primero o no en el OR, o si las dos expresiones se evalúan o sólo la primera; si cambiara el orden de las expresiones o se usara un entorno que evaluara toda la expresión completa seguiría teniendo el mismo problema.

Comment: Verdaderamente tienes razon @SJuan76. Acabo de probar tu observacion y es exactamente como dices. Nunca se deja de aprender. Voy a actualizar mi respuesta. GRACIAS!